# passing parameters in prepareForSegue:

Tags: ios, segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CreateUser"])
    {
       CreateUserViewController *createUserVC = segue.destinationViewController;
       createUserVC.email.text = @"something from fb";
       createUserVC.age.text = @"99";
       createUserVC.name.text = @"Name from fb";     
    }
}
```

I call this segue from my "StartVC." I have another CreateUserViewController which contains different textfields to hold user details. I have no idea why this wouldn't be working, can someone pls enlighten me?
By breakpoints I can see the code is run, and the create user vc is presented, but the fields are empty(only containing placeholder; I do not write the strings blank by = @"" or anything alike)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to make changes to another view controller's view objects.

That violates the principle of encapsulation, an important part of object-oriented design. (It means that other parts of your code, outside of your view controller, depend on the PRESENTATION of your view controller in order to work. If you decide to move views around later, you have to change code that's outside of your view controller. That's bad.)

It's also the reason your code isn't working.

Instead you should set up properties in your destination view controller and set those. Then in your destination view controller's viewDidLoad (only invoked once) or in viewWillAppear (called every time the VC is about to be shown) install the values from your properties into your views as appropriate.

At the time prepareForSegue is called the destination view controller's views haven't been loaded yet. If you look at them you'll find that they are nil. That's why your code isn't working.

Try this test:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CreateUser"])
    {
       CreateUserViewController *createUserVC = segue.destinationViewController;
       NSLog(@"createUserVC.email = %@", createUserVC.email);
       NSLog(@"createUserVC.age = %@", createUserVC.age);
       NSLog(@"createUserVC.name = %@", createUserVC.name);
    }
}
```

You will see that all of those outlets are nil.

Comment: Just to simplify: you're saying I should make properties (let em be strings) in my createuserVC, and then set the textfield according to those strings, when createuserVC loads? Im not sure I understand why accessing a say UIView property from outside is different than accessing some other type(NSString in this case)

Comment: Because a property is a public interface, intended to be used from outside. A view inside a view controller is presentation. It's the way your VC LOOKS. If you have outside code that relies on the view hierarchy of your view controller, then if you make layout changes, you break that dependency.

Comment: Im doing it the other way though: changing how the VC looks from outside

Comment: Right. You should not try to change the way the view controller looks from the outside. You should treat a view controller's views as private and add a public interface of some sort (property or a method of some sort) that ASKS the view controller to change something for you. That way, if you later decide to change the layout of the view controller, you only have to change code in one place (the view controller implementation) in order to complete that change. If code outside the view controller interacts with a view controller's views directly, you have to go find that code and fix it.